# Python lists replace item with variable and fill remainder

Tags: python-3.x, list, discord.py

I am making a word guesser for discord, and I have stumbled upon a problem I can not figure out. Full code [here.](https://mystb.in/PhysicianBlairCross.python)

I have a keyword, a counter, and a wordhelp list. I am calling a function every x seconds, which will add a letter to the wordhelp list, from the keyword, based on the counter.

My question is: How can I start with the wordhelp list being dots for `len(keyword)`, and then replace each dot with it's corresponding letter in the function.

I have tried something like this: `wordhelp[counter] = keyword[counter]` but that gives me this `list assignment index out of range`, because there is no dots in the wordhelp list to be replaced.

```py
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot.counter = 0
        self.bot.keyword = ""
        self.bot.wordhelp = []

    # Called every 60 seconds
    @tasks.loop(seconds=60)
    async def loop_update(self):
        # Add the new letter to the wordhelp list
        self.bot.wordhelp[self.bot.counter] = self.bot.keyword[self.bot.counter]
        # Edit the ini variable embed to show new keyword letter
        await self.bot.ini.edit(embed=discord.Embed(title="Guessing game started!", description=f"Find the keyword starting with:\n`{''.join(self.bot.wordhelp)}`"))
        self.bot.counter += 1
```

Comment: Post your code in the question, not as a link. Preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Sure! Although it's kind of hard, since it's in a class

Comment: What class is `bot`?

Comment: bot is my `commands.Bot` instance, I am assigning the variables to that so they are editable over different functions

Comment: Basically I just need to know how to make the `self.bot.wordhelp` list dots for the length of `self.bot.wordhelp`

Comment: You mean something like `self.bot.wordhelp = ['.']*len(keyword)`?

Comment: Yes! Though now I have the problem that if I put that in the `@tasks.loop`, it will instantiate that wordhelp as dots again and again, so my technique of showing a new letter won't work well, it will only show the latest leter, and the ones before that as dots.

Comment: I fixed that by adding a `:` so, `self.bot.wordhelp[:self.bot.counter] = self.bot.keyword[:self.bot.counter]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!!!!

Comment: Initializing it to all dots shouldn't go in the `task` loop; it should be done once you know then length of `keyword`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping an explicit list of dots, you can just keep a count of how many letters you want to 'reveal', and then create the display dynamically based on that. Something like this:

```
def hidden_word(word, reveal=0):
    hidden = len(word) - reveal
    dots = '.' * hidden
    return word[:reveal] + dots
```

Now you can just feed it the count of how many letters to reveal:

```
word = 'giraffe'
for i in range(len(word)+1):
    print(hidden_word(word, reveal=i))
# Produces:
.......
g......
gi.....
gir....
gira...
giraf..
giraff.
giraffe
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though I have encountered a problem where if for example I wanted the keyword to be multiple words long, the spaces would show up as dots. I am not sure how I could implement a feature where spaces would show up as spaces, and the rest as dots.

Comment: @Buster you could split the words up, hide each one separately based on the counter and then rejoin with `' '.join()`.